# Why did the producers of Spider-Man 3 not want Topher Grace on That 70's Show?

Tags: casting, spider-man-trilogy, that-70s-show

I've been watching [That 70's Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165598/?ref_=nv_sr_2) for some years now. I've wondered why on season 8, Eric Forman (played by [Topher Grace](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0333410/?ref_=tt_ov_st)) was not on the show.

So I looked it up and I saw that during the 8th season, Topher was filming [Spider-Man 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0413300/?ref_=nm_knf_i2), where he played Venom and the producers did not want him to be on the show.

Why is that? What was the purpose of him not being on the show? Could it be something so simple as to not having enough time to film both?

Comment: Can you cite your source for "the producers did not want him on the show"? It seems likely that wherever you found this information, you might also find a reason.

Comment: It was on a forum, I don't remember the name. I wasn't on my pc when I found it

Comment: That's why I asked here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general reason is that Topher Grace, along with Ashton Kutcher, [wanted to move on](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165598/faq#.2.1.6) to other things in his career, particularly acting in films.

Comment: It's a one liner but I also didn't found anything else, so +1.

Comment: Well, I'd say he wanted to _focus_ on movies, because he did do movies while he was still on show, e.g _[Win a Date with Tad Hamilton](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0335559/)_ and _[In Good Company](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0385267/)_).